# How to display API data in a Table format in React JS

Tags: reactjs, api

I have below API response and I want to show them in a table format. In the networkProductsList I have key value pair. Key is column name and value is data for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand is you want to display the networkProductsList in a table.
For that you should change

```
data.map((item) => (
```

to

```
{data?.networkProductsList?.map((item) => (
```

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tree-rnurr?file=/src/App.js)